# less: custom shortcut for previous searches (up-arrow)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, less

The `less` viewer allows some customization using the `~/.lesskey` file, but it does not seem to have any effect in the context of searching. For example, I can map `^P` to the up arrow, and this works for navigating, but as soon as I press `/` and begin a search, `less` completely forgets about all my customizations and instead puts a warty `^P` in the search string.

Is there any way to enable shortcuts during search, so that for example I can access previous searches using `^P` instead of an arrow key that is very far out of reach from my typing position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want customise shortcuts for the line editor, you have to put it in a `#line-edit` section in `~/.lesskey`:

```
#line-edit
^P up
^N down
```

See `man lesskey` for details.

Comment: Thanks, I read `man lesskey` many times over, but I assumed that `#any-text` could only possibly be a comment, since that is the common convention.